# LXTerminal sometimes not maximised

Tags: openbox, autostart

I have an autostart script, which runs several commands in an `LXTerminal`. But sometimes the window isn't maximised, which it's supposed to be according to my `~/.config/openbox/rc.xml`. Can someone explain to me

- why this happens?
- why it does only sometimes?
- how to fix this?

my `~/.config/openbox/rc.xml`:

```
[…]
<application name="lxterminal"> 
  <maximized>true</maximized>
</application>
[…]
```